# Lodash sort according to the provided comparator

Tags: javascript, sorting, typescript, lodash

Is it possible to sort by a provided  comparator by any lodash function?

For instance I have class Person:

`class Person{name: string; age: numbert}`

and then I want to sort people in the way that people of age 0 are in the end and rest is sorted in the ascending order? People are of type `{}`.

```
_.sortBy(people, (p1,p2) => { 
          if(p1.age == 0) return -1; 
      return p1.age - p2.age 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly hacky, but this will work:

```
_.sortBy(people, [p => p.age || Infinity])
```

Comment: Why not using `Infinity`?